# Можно ли добавиться в исключения?

Tags: c++, c, windows

Можно ли добавиться (программно себя) в исключения Firewall'a?
Пишу аналог Bittorrent. Постоянно Firewall беспокоится, что-то чует, не знает что.
Речь идет о сторонних Firewall. Да и Windows Firewall тоже мне таблички разноцветные показывает какие-то.

P.S. Ну, или как можно сделать так, чтобы они доверяли моему процессу?
Можно как-то с ними договориться?

Comment: Добавление правил для Windows Firewall: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ics/c-adding-a-service-rule

Answer (score 3):

Насчет именно программно, вызовом функции WinAPI, не скажу, а через вызов Net shell можно. Функцией `system` или `ShellExecute` выполняете команду

```
netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="имя правила" dir=in action=allow program="путь к программе" enable=yes
```

Команда должна выполняться от администратора, с поднятием привилегий. В нормальной ситуации ее запускает инсталлятор. В скрипте InnoSetup, например, она выглядит так:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{sys}\netsh.exe"; Parameters: "advfirewall firewall add rule name=""имя правила"" dir=in action=allow program=""{app}\программа.exe"" enable=yes"; Flags: runhidden skipifdoesntexist; Description: "Adding firewall rule for моя программа"; StatusMsg: "Adding firewall rules..."
```

Это, разумеется, для Windows Firewall. Про брандмауэры других производителей надо спрашивать у этих самых производителей.

Answer (score 0):

Краткий ответ - так просто - нельзя. Если бы можно было, то все вирусы и трояны давно бы добавили себя в исключения и грош цена была всем фаерволам.

По хорошему - нужно получать сертификат, подписывать свое приложение и потом договариваться с другими фаерволами/антивирусами, что бы они Ваше приложение пропускали.

Но обычно, такие программы разрабатывают с выключенных фаерволом (ужас-ужас) или настраивают ручками, что бы папка с исходниками была в исключениях.